# Blocked Vs. Incomplete Test Case Status

Tags: manual-testing, testcase

What types of things define whether you should mark a test case as Incomplete versus Blocked?

i.e.

- no Data to use the Sorting/Filtering
- lack of Users with Correct permissions
- etc.

I searched and only found one definition

> A test case that cannot be executed because the preconditions for its
>   execution are not fulfilled.

Comment: Obs: Empty sets of data are perfectly valid test cases for sorting and filtering features.

Comment: @JoãoFarias please post an answer so that you can receive credit.  but I disagree, if there is no data to sort, how do you know that the data sorted?

Comment: 1 - It´s not related to the question, it was just an observation on your answer. 2 - Try run _[].sort()_ on your browser console. You can an empty list - not an exception or null. An empty list is sorted by nature - but code could not handle this correctly and return something different. Same idea for filtering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have found pretty much clearly defines when to set `blocked` status for the test.

You set `blocked` when something is blocking you from executing the test case.

You set `incomplete` when you set execution on pause/hold and then realize you do not need to continue.

Answer (score 3):

Blocked test case is a test case that cannot run because the preconditions for its execution are not fulfilled. While, Incomplete test cases are which cannot complete execution for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Ive come across this a lot with testers setting test cases to failed because there wasn't enough data to complete the test.

Example:
Test case - Clicking "View receipt button" should render 10 most recent receipts.
Step 1: Go to Page > Economy > Reports (expected: Receipts page is loaded)
Step 2: Click "View receipt button"(expect: receipts to render based on date)
Step 3: Double click any receipt (expect: chosen receipt to open in modal)

lets say that there isn't any receipts in the current test database. Im of the opinion that this test should be set to blocked or not applicable rather than failed since the outcome cant be tested due to lack of data in the test db. Lack of data doesn't mean that the developer(s) havent met their requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Test case management tools used by software testing companies have multiple test case statuses like pass, fail, block, In execution, Incomplete, Not run.

1. Blocked - Test case status is marked blocked, if test case is
   blocking any feature.
2. Incomplete - If the test case is not as per the requirement of business analyst or execution has been stopped in between.

Comment: your statement `if test case is blocking any feature` is a bit confusing, could you please elaborate?  A Test Case should not block a Feature.

Answer (score -1):

Test Case should be marked as Blocked in case any feature is not functional at all.
Moreover for Incomplete or Impeded completely depends on the story/business requirement.

Comment: if a Feature is "*not functional at all*" the test case should be marked as a fail and a Defect/Bug should be written